# My elements are too close together. How do I space my nav elements in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want my nav elements to be placed to the right of my webpage and it is. No problems there. My issue is that my nav elements are too close together. I expect them to be more spaced out. What is wrong here and what do I need to do?

```css
nav {
  text-align: right;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Calibri', 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  color: black;
}

nav a {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Calibri', 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav>

  <a href="#">Gaming</a>

  <a href="#">Wishlist</a>

  <a href="#">Merch</a>

  <a href="#">Contact</a>

</nav>
```

Comment: What spacing? Horizontally or vertically? What does your html look like? What does the page look like now? How do you want the page to look?

Comment: Apply some left-right margin to the anchor tags like this: `nav a {margin: 0 15px;}`

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a lot of solutions:

1. Adding padding or margin to your `a` inside the nav
2. Gap property

```
gap: 5px; // 5px for exmaple
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give margin in nav a instead of nav if you want want space between your nav elements

```css
nav {
  text-align: right;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Calibri', 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  color: black;
}

nav a {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Calibri', 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
margin:0 20px
}
```

```html
<nav>

  <a href="#">Gaming</a>

  <a href="#">Wishlist</a>

  <a href="#">Merch</a>

  <a href="#">Contact</a>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex:

```
display: flex;
justify-content:flex-end;
```

This code make your elements align right.